# ASP .NET MVC layer DAL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have an ASP .NET MVC 6 and Entity Framework 6, divided into layers , how do I get the connection string in the DAL layer in my DbContext ?
The connection string is in appsettings.json file like this:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Verbose",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "",
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess you add an constructor with said parameters and push it through?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the connection string in `appsettings.json` you want to build a configuration object first:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
var configuration = builder.Build();
```

This should probably be in `Startup`'s ctor. You can then store the `configuration` object in a field. Let's say a `_configuration` field.

Then you can do

```
// _connectionString is also a field.
_connectionString = _configuration["Data:DefaultConnection"];
```

Your `DbContext`:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
    }
}
```

The you can register your `AppDbContext` in `ConfigureServices` as:

```
services.AddScoped(_ => new AppDbContext(_connectionString));
```

Comment: Thank you , now how do I run the query in my repository class?

Comment: It should be easy from here, if you're using `DI` then simply request `AppDbContext` in your repository's ctor. After that, do your queries using `AppDbContext` as you always do. If you're just starting with either `EntityFramework` or `Asp.Net Core` then please tell us so that we know how to help you best.